# Getting latest data from SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble getting the latest data out of this.

I have a table with these data:

```
ItemId, ShipmentId, Date
```

Items can be shipped many times and a shipment can contain multiple items.
I need to get the latest shipment for every item.

Table looks like this:

```
11  12 2011-05-13 
11  2  2011-07-01 
12  2  2000-03-02
...
```

The result should be

```
11 2 2011-07-01
12 2 2000-03-02
```

I can't find a solution to be exclusive.
How can I get the latest shipment for every item?

Comment: Thank you for all your post Damien_The_Unbeliever got the solution for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're working with a database engine that supports ranking functions, use a CTE or subquery to order the results:

```
;With OrderedItems as (
     select ItemId,ShipmentId,Date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER By Date desc) as rn
     from ItemsTable
)
select * from OrderedItems where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.ItemId, t1.ShipmentId, t1.Date
from tab t1
join (
    select ItemId, max(Date) as Date
    from tab
    group by ItemId
) t on t1.ItemId = t.ItemId and t1.Date = t.Date
```

Comment: That won't select the shipmentId that belongs to the latest shipment date.

Comment: if i try your solution i get error: Column 'ShipID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it, but this general idea should work:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE T2
        WHERE T1.ItemId = T2.ItemId AND T1.Date < T2.Date
    )
```

In plain English: select rows such that there is no other row with the same `ItemId` but later `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rank() also in CTE

```
;With Ordered as (
     select ItemId,ShipmentId,dates,
         rank() OVER ( PARTITION by itemID ORDER By dates desc) as DateRank
     from ItemsTable
)
select * from Ordered where DateRank = 1
```